# how to explicitly lock a particular document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how to explicitly lock a particular document in mongodb?

for ex: N No of clients accessing a document in mongodb collection, If write operation comes than the read operations should lock until the write needs to be complete, These are all needs to be done in document level. can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Suganth A.

Answer (score 0):

A write locks a document. You do not have to do anything.

**EDIT: removed this answer**:

Use the `update` function from MongoDB. All reads after the update will read the correct data.

Comment: No, instead of the write, which I assumed you do with first a `find` and then a `save`.

Comment: Because that would give problems, or at least, not always intuitive results. Otherwise, there is no need to lock for a write. The write will always lock the document.

Comment: sorry boss, am new to mongodb i couldn't get you what exactly you are saying.

Comment: ok thankq gotta idea. there is any option to lock a document explicitly?

Comment: I don't believe so. Here is a way to mimic it. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/10/mongodb-pessimistic-locking/.